# Position of squares on a checkerboard from a sequence of numbers

Tags: algorithms

I want to position squares on a checkerboard in such a way that they fill the square they are on.

[image]

How do I calculate the position of one of those orange squares such that $f(i) = x,y$ coordinate, $i$ being the number of the orange square starting from $0$.

Also, the size of the checkerboard is not definite, I need the pattern to repeat for any size of the checkerboard horizontally and vertically.

With a checkerboard height of 5 instead of 4.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to play with how many times you have reached $5.$ They way to do this is with division, so taking ceils is the right approach. The row is just $\left \lfloor \frac{i}{5}\right \rfloor,$ the column depends on which row are we. It is $5\times \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{i}{5}\right \rfloor}{5}\right \rfloor +i\pmod 5.$ This gives you
$$f(i)=\left (5\times \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{i}{5}\right \rfloor}{5}\right \rfloor +\left(i\pmod 5)\right )\, ,\, 
\left \lfloor \frac{i}{5}\right \rfloor\right ).$$
here the columns and rows are indexed starting at $0.$
The code in sage looks like:

```
A = [[0 for i in range(0,10)] for j in range(0,10)]
for i in range(0,50):
    x = i//5
    y = 5*(x//5) + i%5
    A[x][y]=i+1
for i in range(0,10):
    print(A[i])
```

**Edit:**
Your new formula will have to have a period of $2$ that alternates it.
The code for your new pattern looks like

```
  A = [[0 for i in range(0,20)] for j in range(0,20)]
    for i in range(0,25*8):
        x = i//10
        tal = (i%10)//5
        retal = (i//50)%2
        y = 5*retal + 5*tal+ i%10
        A[x][y]=i+1
    for i in range(0,20):
        print(A[i])
```

**Edit 2:**
For any height and even width, the following does what you want

```
h = 4
w = 8
A = [[0 for i in range(0,5*w)] for j in range(0,5*h)]
for i in range(0,(h*w*25)/2):
    ww = ceil(w/2)*5
    x = i//ww
    tal = (i%ww)//5
    retal = (i//(ww*5))%2
    y = 5*retal + 5*tal+i%ww
    if x<h*5 and y<5*w:
        A[x][y]=1+i
for i in range(0,5*h):
    print(A[i])
```

The explanation is the same as before, so I am not sure what is unclear or why you keep changing the size instead of generalizing it. Why is the odd width case different? How to fix it?

Comment: I updated my picture, I also want the pattern to repeat on a checkerboard horizontally and vertically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by shifting this 4 times?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. The thing I should have said is I also want the pattern to repeat forever.

Comment: What would I have to change in the new formula to change the height of the checkerboard from 4 to 5?

Comment: I added a picture to clarify.